# PyPDF pdf merge--TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to use pypdf in python to merge two pdfs. This is running in my Flask server. My code is as follows:

```py
@website.route('/test-pypdf', methods=('GET',))
def test_pypdf():
    with open('document.pdf', 'rb') as inFile, open('overlay.pdf', 'rb') as overlay:
        original = PdfReader(inFile)
        background = original.pages[0]
        print(inFile)
        print(background)
        print(type(background))
        foreground = PdfReader(overlay)
        o = foreground.pages[0]
        print(o)
        print(type(o))

        # merge the first two pages
        background.merge_page(o)

    return 'success'
```

This prints out:

```
<_io.BufferedReader name='document.pdf'>
{'/Type': '/Page', '/Resources': {'/ProcSet': ['/PDF', '/Text', '/ImageB', '/ImageC', '/ImageI'], '/ExtGState': {'/G3': (3, 0)}, '/XObject': {'/X4': (4, 0)}}, '/MediaBox': ['0', '0', '612', '792'], '/Contents': (5, 0), '/StructParents': '0', '/Parent': {'/Type': '/Pages', '/Count': '1', '/Kids': [{...}]}}
<class 'pdfrw.objects.pdfdict.PdfDict'>
{'/Contents': (4, 0), '/Group': {'/Type': '/Group', '/S': '/Transparency', '/CS': '/DeviceRGB'}, '/Parent': {'/Count': '1', '/Kids': [{...}], '/MediaBox': ['0', '0', '595.28', '841.89'], '/Type': '/Pages'}, '/Resources': (8, 0), '/Type': '/Page'}
<class 'pdfrw.objects.pdfdict.PdfDict'>
```

It also causes this error:

> background.merge_page(o)

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

But as you can see, they are not NoneTypes.

I tried switching the order to o.merge_page(background) and using different pdfs to no avail. This works just fine when I run it in the terminal but not on my Flask server. Btw this is all on a Digital Ocean droplet.

Any ideas?

Update:
When I run it as a script it prints slightly different text:

```
<_io.BufferedReader name='document.pdf'>
{'/Type': '/Page', '/Resources': {'/ProcSet': ['/PDF', '/Text', '/ImageB', '/ImageC', '/ImageI'], '/ExtGState': {'/G3': IndirectObject(3, 0, 139969018068944)}, '/XObject': {'/X4': IndirectObject(4, 0, 139969018068944)}}, '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/Contents': IndirectObject(5, 0, 139969018068944), '/StructParents': 0, '/Parent': IndirectObject(6, 0, 139969018068944)}
<class 'pypdf._page.PageObject'>
{'/Contents': IndirectObject(4, 0, 139969009072496), '/Group': {'/Type': '/Group', '/S': '/Transparency', '/CS': '/DeviceRGB'}, '/Parent': IndirectObject(1, 0, 139969009072496), '/Resources': IndirectObject(8, 0, 139969009072496), '/Type': '/Page', '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 595.27999999999997, 841.88999999999999]}
<class 'pypdf._page.PageObject'>
```

The printed text seems to be the same except that the IndirectObjects printed from the python script become tuples without a third element in the Flask script. The MediaBox in Flask contains Strings rather than ints like in the Python script, and the Python script MediaBox ints contain way more decimal places (seems rounded to two decimal places in the Flask output).

I use the same venv and it's not throwing an error when I use pypdf.PdfReader().

What does the different printed text mean? And how do I fix that?

Update 2:

I solved it by switching to pypdf2 (which I understand will no longer be updated and was recently merged into pypdf) and edited the following code I found on Stackoverflow:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader,PdfFileWriter
import sys

f = sys.argv[1]
k = sys.argv[2]
print f, k
file1 = PdfFileReader(open(f, "rb"))
file2 = PdfFileReader(open(k, "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
page = file1.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(file2.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)

with open("join.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
    output.write(outputStream)
```

And... it worked. Perfectly. The original problem remains unsolved but I'm content with just using pypdf2.

Comment: Wait...`This works just fine on my laptop but not on my Flask server.` are you saying this is Flask specific? Have you installed the right packages on your DO server?...you don't show any imports here...

Comment: Meant to say it runs fine on the Ubuntu server in terminal, but it also runs fine on my laptop. The same Ubuntu server that is running my Flask app. I have pypdf 3.15.0 on both and it isn't throwing any errors when I import PdfReader so I believe that's working fine.

Comment: _But as you can see, they are not NoneTypes_ No, I cannot see that.  You're printing `o`, but the problem is not with `o` itself; the problem is with `background.merge_page`.  You're apparently expecting `background.merge_page` to be a callable function, but it is not --  it is `None`.

Comment: @JohnGordon if I put the function in a script and run it, it runs just fine. It only throws the NoneType error when I attempt to run it in my Flask app.

Comment: Are you sure it's reading the same file in both cases?  The code opens `document.pdf` in _the current directory_.  Is the current directory the same in your script and in the flask app?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, I am running them both in the same directory. Just to make sure, I had the Flask app write a file to its directory, and it wrote into the same directory. They are definitely accessing the same files.

Comment: @JohnGordon Check the update when you have a chance please, the printed text is slightly different and that is probably why it is not working. I am not sure why the printed text is different. Also thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it. This problem has me stumped.

Comment: @ViaTech I ran it in the same directory using the same venv. It works in the script but not in the Flask app. The PdfReader() objects are slightly different as outlined in the update. I could not fix that, so I switched to PyPDF2 and mergePage and now it works perfectly. Thank you for your help!